# How can I make PM2 print to it's log whether a restart was manual or because it crashed?

Tags: node.js, logging, pm2

I'm trying to figure out why my app is crashing.

When I look through my PM2 log file (www-out-0.log) I can see it restarting, but can't tell if it was because I typed in `pm2 restart all`, or because my app crashed and PM2 restarted it.

How can I make it print out this important information?

Comment: run `pm2 logs`?

Comment: thats how im looking at them, but i cant tell why it restared